# how to use created columns in SQL without showing these in the end result?

Tags: sql

I have a long string from which I want to split columns using delimiter _

I know how to get the location using `CHARINDEX` and am going to use `SUBSTRING()` to get the correct information out.
But to keep the code clean and avoid having to use a lot of nesting, I create columns which has the location of the delimiter using the code below. But now they show up in my end result as well. Is it possible to "store" these values without creating a whole column?

```
SELECT TOP 5
   CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, 0) AS first_lower,
   CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, first_lower+1) AS second_lower,
```

I want to avoid having to use nesting like:

```
SUBSTRING(SALESID, CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, 0))-1, 1)
```

Comment: How do you intend to use these with substring? Inside the query? Can you include it?

Comment: "keep the code clean and avoid having to use a lot of nesting" -> what kind of nesting are you talking about? To keep the code "clean" you can simply add new lines in the query and keep using complex statements, I don't see the need here to store the char index for all selected rows, you should use it directly in the `SUBSTRING()` IMO

Comment: To avoid having to use:
SUBSTRING(SALESID, CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, 0))-1, 1)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (CHARINDEX and TOP are product specific.)

Comment: @Kaddath, That would result in a really long hard to read line..

Comment: Not trying to be pretentious but if you think this is a long and complex SQL line you've seen nothing, I see much worse on a daily basis. Seems pretty straightforward to me, in my work we try to avoid things that consume resources just for the sake of presentation..

Comment: @Kaddath, you are right but the problem is that in my issue it goes up to eleventh lower (in contrast to the second_lower stated in the example I gave)

Comment: I see, for mySQL I would personnally create a function to make it more readable in that case (or use new lines as I said), but as I see, SQL Server seems to have a dedicated function [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only return `MySubstringValue` column in the end result.

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(...) As MySubstringValue
FROM
(
   SELECT TOP 5
      CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, 0) AS first_lower,
      CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, first_lower+1) AS second_lower
   FROM xxx
) tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CTE (Common Table Expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to structure complex queries and make them a bit more readable/manageable. Something like this:

```sql
;WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, 0) AS first_lower, * FROM MyTable)
,CTE2 AS (SELECT CHARINDEX('_', SALESID, first_lower+1) AS second_lower, * FROM CTE1)
,CTE3 AS (SELECT SUBSTRING(SALESID, first_lower, second_lower - first_lower) AS calculated_column, * FROM CTE2)
SELECT SALESID, ...
FROM CTE3
WHERE calculated_column = 'qwerty'
```